# can't publish to pubnub when my finger lifts up from joystick

Tags: android, pubnub, app-inventor

I have a joystick interface app build on MIT app inventor. When I move the joystick, data is published to Pubnub. However, I want to implement a code which publishes data when I lift up my finger from the app (.TouchUp function) but not able to do so.

I have inserted the same code for publishing but getting no response when I lift my finger.

I expect to receive integer number '0' on microcontroller debug but not receiving anything.

Image of block:-
[image: block of code which has problems]

Why is the above line 'call publish' not getting executed?

Example code which gets executed:-
[image: example code which sends the data]

Comment: I don't know AI events, but can you put some sort of debug output in that `TouchUp` action to prove that it is getting invoked? If it is is getting invoked, how do you know that PubNub `publish` is not getting invoked?

Comment: Checking in to see if you have any further data for us on this based on my comment above.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. I know its getting invoked when I receive the output on my Arduino IDE debug console.